# JavaScript Stopwatch - Trouble Displaying a Leading Digit

Tags: javascript, timer, intervals, stopwatch, digits

I've been trying to create a simple stopwatch script using JavaScript in order to display the number of seconds, minutes, and hours that have elapsed.

Ideally, I'd like to have the time displayed as follows:

`hh:mm:ss`

With JavaScript, I was unable to find a built-in way to format numbers such that they contain a leading zero if a number is only one digit in length. This is where my problem lies - the logic that I added to the script to add a leading "0" works for the `seconds` display, but not for the `minutes` or `hours` displays.

Instead of only adding a leading "0" and then the one-digit value, the code I wrote will add in a "0" for *each iteration* of the `setInterval()` function, creating a long string of "0"s and then the current `minutes` or `hours` values.

I'm having trouble understanding why that is happening for the `minutes` and `hours` sections, but **not** for the `seconds` section when the code being used is the same.

In theory, I know that I'm essentially just adding another "0" to a string that then gets displayed each time the `setInterval()` function executes, but I can't seem to figure out why that doesn't happen in the `seconds` section. And what's also interesting is that the leading "0"s don't start getting added until the timer reaches two seconds.

Please see below for the code that I wrote for this stopwatch script. I'd certainly appreciate any insight that anyone could provide to get this working as expected.

```js
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;

function stopWatch(){

//Increment seconds on each "tick" of the stopwatch
seconds++;

//Check if minutes or hours needs to be incremented (which should happen every 60 seconds or 60 minutes, resepctively)
if(seconds / 60 == 0){
 seconds = 0;
 minutes++;

 if(minutes / 60 == 0){
  minutes = 0;
  hours++;
 }

}

//If the number of elapsed seconds, minutes, or hours is less than 10, add a 0 to the front of the number.
if(seconds < 10){
 seconds = "0" + seconds;
}

if(minutes < 10){
 minutes = "0" + minutes;
}

if(hours < 10){
 hours = "0" + hours;
}

//Print the results to the "display" div in the HTML
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

}

//Run the stopWatch() function every 1000ms
window.setInterval(stopWatch, 1000);
```

```html
 <div id="display">00:00:00</div>
```

And for what it's worth, I kept the `<script></script>` tags in the HTML document for simplicity, but once I get it working, I'll likely move the script to its own `script.js` file and potentially add in some buttons to start, stop, and reset the stopwatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;
let seconds_string = "0";
let minutes_string = "0";
let hours_string = "0";

function stopWatch(){

//Increment seconds on each "tick" of the stopwatch
seconds++;

//Check if minutes or hours needs to be incremented (which should happen every 60 seconds or 60 minutes, resepctively)
if(seconds / 60 === 1){
 seconds = 0;
 minutes++;

 if(minutes / 60 === 1){
  minutes = 0;
  hours++;
 }

}

//If the number of elapsed seconds, minutes, or hours is less than 10, add a 0 to the front of the number.
if(seconds < 10){
 seconds_string = "0" + seconds.toString();
} else {
    seconds_string = seconds.toString();
}

if(minutes < 10){
 minutes_string = "0" + minutes.toString();
} else {
    minutes_string = minutes.toString();
}

if(hours < 10){
 hours_string = "0" + hours.toString();
} else {
    hours_string = hours.toString();
}

//Print the results to the "display" div in the HTML
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = hours_string + ":" + minutes_string + ":" + seconds_string;

}

//Run the stopWatch() function every 1000ms
window.setInterval(stopWatch, 1000);
```

```html
 <div id="display">00:00:00</div>
```

Comment: Fixes string problem and logic issue with going from seconds to minute and minutes to hour

Comment: Thanks for the response. I rewrote my code to include a "display" variable for the "hours", "minutes", and "seconds" that should be displayed. However, now I'm running into an issue where the "minutes" and "seconds" variables aren't updating... The "seconds" variable is the only one that updates, despite the code that should cause it to reset to 0 after 60 iterations. Here's a Gist that shows the code I have now: [https://gist.github.com/JamieMcGibbon/96ec7bf7f1db4d563adb984fd9254a7f](https://gist.github.com/JamieMcGibbon/96ec7bf7f1db4d563adb984fd9254a7f).

Comment: @Jamirmcg You have to change the `if` checks to `seconds / 60 === 1` and `minutes / 60 === 1`

Comment: Ah, makes sense! I was using a modulus operation when I first wrote the code, which is probably why I was checking for `seconds / 60 == 0` and `minutes / 60 == 0`. Thanks for the prompt response!

Comment: @Jamiemcg No problem. If you have your answer, then make sure to mark one of the answers as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

When you do "0" + minutes (and seconds, and hours) those variables get automatically converted into a string, consisting of two characters, a zero and something else.

Since the variables carry through each iteration, the next time you are adding another "0" character to the beginning of the string, and so-on.

The reason it's not happening to seconds is because you are converting seconds BACK to an int at the beginning of the loop when you do seconds++. So it becomes a string, then an int, then a string, etc.

To see this in action, try this snippet:

```
var test = 1;
console.log( typeof test );  //outputs "number"
test = "0" + test;
console.log( typeof test ); //outputs "string"
test++;
console.log( typeof test); //outputs number
```

My suggestion would be to separate counting units from display units. See if minutes is less than 10, and if so set outputMinutes to "0" + minutes. Do the same for seconds and hours. Then you just change the outputMinutes, outputSeconds, and outputHours each time, while the actual minutes, seconds, and hours variables remain as integers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I rewrote my code to include a "display" variable for the "hours", "minutes", and "seconds" that should be displayed. However, now I'm running into an issue where the "minutes" and "seconds" variables aren't updating... The "seconds" variable is the only one that updates, despite the code that should cause it to reset to 0 after 60 iterations. Here's a Gist that shows the code I have now: [https://gist.github.com/JamieMcGibbon/96ec7bf7f1db4d563adb984fd9254a7f](https://gist.github.com/JamieMcGibbon/96ec7bf7f1db4d563adb984fd9254a7f).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of test in the `if` if the value is less than 10, test the length of that value as a string, if it is less than 2 (which means any number less than 10 in this case), then you add another `"0"` as a string to the value;

Like below:

```js
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;

function stopWatch(){
  seconds++;
  
  if(seconds / 60 == 0){
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;
    if(minutes / 60 == 0){
      minutes = 0;
      hours++;
    }
  }

  if(seconds.toString().length < 2){
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }
  
  if(minutes.toString().length < 2){
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }

  if(hours.toString().length < 2){
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}

window.setInterval(stopWatch, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="display">00:00:00</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I rewrote my code to include a "display" variable for the "hours", "minutes", and "seconds" that should be displayed. However, now I'm running into an issue where the "minutes" and "seconds" variables aren't updating... The "seconds" variable is the only one that updates, despite the code that should cause it to reset to 0 after 60 iterations. Here's a Gist that shows the code I have now: [https://gist.github.com/JamieMcGibbon/96ec7bf7f1db4d563adb984fd9254a7f](https://gist.github.com/JamieMcGibbon/96ec7bf7f1db4d563adb984fd9254a7f).

Comment: You can create a new question with that issue and share the link here with me